# Java native launcher performance

Tags: java, performance

I have a program written in Java and a native launcher written in C++, based on a sample at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17352/JVM-Launcher. A strange thing is that running my program with my native launcher take more CPU than using `java.exe` (~5% vs 15-20%). I have been giving this situation some thought but it still doesn't make much sense. I've tried increasing the JVM heap size, (re)built the native launcher in release mode, used different JRE version(1.6_24, 1.6_31, 1.7_03) but no luck.

Does anybody have a suggestion for how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide us with the sources (both C++ and Java)? Without knowing what your program does, it is really difficult to say anything.

Comment: I've found where's the problem, it's the use of `-Djava.compiler=NONE` which cause jvm launch in debug mode.

Comment: care to close the question, since you found an answer?

Comment: The JVM does not run in "debug mode" but in "interpreter mode". The Java compiler option enables the JIT just-in-time compiler which converts Java bytecode into native code.

Comment: @TheAlchemist How do I close my question?

Comment: A self answer would be more appropriate, since other users might run into the same problem, and find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Providing this answer to move the OP's comment to answer.

The problem was that the C++ program was running the native launcher with the `-Djava.compiler=NONE` setting, which essentially set the JVM to run in "interpretive" mode, disabling JIT (just-in-time) compilation of java bytecode to native code, which naturally makes run slower as the bytecode needs to be interpreted every time it is executed.